# How to update ChromeDriver binary file on Ubuntu

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am working with `Python / Selenium / Chrome / ChromeDriver` to do testing, scraping, etc. Actually trying to replace `cdc_` string with something else. When I opened file using `vim` and replace `cdc_` string with `cat_` nothing has changed. I do believe, I must rebuild it again. How can I rebuild this file ? Any ideas ?

As a reference, I am using this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/41220267#41220267).

```bash
sudo vim -b /home/chromedriver
```

Then I replace `cdc_` with `cat_` and save file. When I executed `Selenium` again, `cdc_` was still available in the console.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you using [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/)? As of Selenium 4.6+, you no longer need to manage drivers yourself. If you set it up correctly, Selenium will download and install the driver for you and use it to run your script.

Comment: @JeffC Hi. Everything is installed and working fine . My issue is how to rebuild an existing binary file of `ChromeDriver`. I am using `Selenium 4.17.2`.

Comment: Ah... I misunderstood. I thought you meant update Chromedriver as in replace the currently installed chromedriver.exe with the latest driver version not actually build the exe yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your goal is to remove these `cdc_` items from Chrome that appear when using `chromedriver`...

[image: "cdc_" in the Devtools console]

...then that's what [SeleniumBase UC Mode](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/help_docs/uc_mode.md) is for.

After `pip install seleniumbase`, you can run seleniumbase scripts that bypass CAPTCHAs, such as:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(uc=True)
driver.uc_open_with_reconnect("https://top.gg/", 5)
driver.quit()
```

Or:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    sb.driver.uc_open_with_reconnect("https://top.gg/", 5)
```

SeleniumBase UC Mode is just one of many available modes of the [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) framework that extends Selenium/WebDriver with a lot more abilities and improvements.

Comment: Thanks for your input ! I am going to try this library.

Comment: Works like a charm ! Seems like, it does not require to modify binary file at all. I am going to dig into the source code on the weekend. Thanks ! (FYI, your answer will be upvoted once I achieve 15 reputation).

Comment: Awesome! You can mark it as the accepted answer without reputation.